# Threading or multiprocessing implementation into face detection/ Tkinter app

Tags: multithreading, opencv, tkinter, python-multiprocessing, face-detection

So basically I have an app that has a splash screen Tkinter frame.

I need this frame to close when openCV detects a face, after which openCV opens a window that shows the camera feed and starts tracking smiles. The other classes initialized in the code below are for updating a database and playing a DTMF tone when a smile is recognized, my main issue is that the mainloop from the Tkinter frame won't allow any other processes to continue.

I also need the Tkinter frame to close when a face is detected. Right now I tried setting it up with a separate face detection loop dedicated just to closing the frame (the frames class has a **`facefound()`** function which just calls a **`self.destroy()`**).

I need to multiprocess the frame's mainloop so that the face detector can actually check whether or not a face is in view.

Current code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import datetime
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
from chocolate_returner import Choco_returner
from given_resetter import Given_resetter
from tone_player import Tone_player
from play_flagger import Play_flagger
from Welcome_frame import Intro
import time


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--picamera", type=int, default=-1,
                help="whether or not the Raspberry Pi camera should be used")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())



faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('faces.xml')
smileCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('smiles.xml')


cap = VideoStream(usePiCamera=args["picamera"] > 0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)


while True:

    framex = cap.read()  # Capture frame-by-frame
    frame = imutils.resize(framex, width=400)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=0

    )
    # ---- Draw a rectangle around the faces

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print "found ", len(faces), "faces"
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]


        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    if (len(faces) > 0):
        check = True
        it.facefound()
        break


while True:

    framex = cap.read() # Capture frame-by-frame
    frame = imutils.resize(framex, width=400)


    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor= 1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=0

    )
    # ---- Draw a rectangle around the faces

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print "found ", len(faces), "faces"
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        smile = smileCascade.detectMultiScale(
            roi_gray,
            scaleFactor= 1.7,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(5, 5),
            flags=0
        )
        time.sleep(2.0)
        # Set region of interest for smiles
        for (x, y, w, h) in smile:
            print "Found", len(smile), "smiles!"

            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 1)
            img = framex

            cv2.imwrite("test.jpg", img)

            cr = Choco_returner()
            gr = Given_resetter()
            tp = Tone_player()
            pf = Play_flagger()


            if (len(smile) > 0):

                return1 = cr.returner()
                tp.play(str(return1[1]), str(return1[2]))
                pf.flag(return1[0])


                #print "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
                # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break




cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: tkinter has `tk.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to run function periodically. maybe you could use it (instead of `while True`) to run your function periodically .